# (install gym environment) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, codec, openai-gym

When I try to install my custom OpenAI gym environment `gym-foo` I get this error

**INPUT:** `pip install -e gym-foo`

**OUTPUT:**

```
Obtaining file:///home/gym-foo
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/.conda/envs/torch/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/home/gym-foo/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/home/gym-foo/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /scratch/6368105.1.gpu.q/pip-pip-egg-info-gtys289c
         cwd: /home/gym-foo/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/.conda/envs/torch/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
        (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 41: invalid start byte
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have found solutions regarding unicode errors but I am not at all familiar with unicode/ascii jargon. Does anyone have a quick fix?

**Note:** I have run `pip install -U setuptools` and to my knowledge there are no non-ASCII characters in the code I have written.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your pip:

```
pip install -U pip
```

This worked for me.

Comment: What about setting the python encoding before executing your installation? `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8`